# Encoding Video into Streamable File Format for YouTube

Tags: video, ffmpeg, youtube

I'm converting an mp3 + image into a video for YouTube. I successfully got the video, but always get this message:

> Your videos will process faster if you encode into a streamable file format.

I tried adding flags I saw recommended from other resources to make it suitable for YouTube, but it still gives me this message.

Here is my ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "$image" -i "$mp3" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -c:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k -r:a 48000 -movflags faststart -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p "$mp4"
```

Comment: I've gotten that error before. But it pops up randomly. One month, I upload videos and there's no warning. Couple of months later, render with same settings and there's that error or the warning about A/V sync. Unless, processing is very slow, I would ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `-flags +cgop` causes this. [Youtube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171) mentions its pipeline handling closed-gop better than open-gop.

Maybe give it a `-tune stillimage` and limit lossy-lossy-reencoding for better audio quality. There's also a basic [how to](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/YouTube) on the wiki for that.